# Как создать такой Tab Bar в iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Как сделать таб бар, где первый элемент зависит от выбранного значения?

Идея такова: есть таб бар с 2мя вкладками: основная вкладка и настройки.
В основной вкладке может быть один из 2х вью контроллеров (клиент или водитель) значение которого выбирается в вкладке настройки(через segmented control).

Т.е. в настройках выбрал значение "водитель" - нажал на кнопку "Сохранить" и попал на основную вкладку где загрузился вью контроллер Водителя. Далее через настройки выбрал значение "Клиент" - сохранил и попал на основную вкладку где загрузился вью контроллер Клиента.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

**UPD.** Попробовал вот так:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[ClientViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClientViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Во второй вкладке есть кнопка перехода на первую вкладку через:
    ClientViewController *ViewController = [[ClientViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ClientViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:ViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

И после этого таб бар исчезает.

Comment: учите матчасть.

Comment: Открыл кучу туториалов. Никак не могу понять:(
Через пару часов пойму:)